# Type 'NSDictionary.Iterator.Element' (aka '(key: Any, value: Any)') has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdictionary

The following function where I iterate through the items in the plist, this worked fine in Swift 1, maybe Swift 2, but definitely not Swift 3.  After making an attempt to redefine the NSDictionary as Dictionary instead, it asks for the types that will be stored in the dictionary but when trying different variations such as string or even any, it doesn't compile.  Therefore I switched back to keeping it as an NSDictionary but this error has me stumped:

```
Type 'NSDictionary.Iterator.Element' (aka '(key: Any, value: Any)') has no subscript members
```

This error shows up when setting the constants: point, title, typeRawValue, and subtitle.

```
    func addAttractionPins() {

            var myDict: NSDictionary?
            if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GeorgiaHumanAnnotations", ofType: "plist"){
                myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)
            }
            if let dict = myDict {
                for attraction in dict {
                    let point = CGPointFromString(attraction["location"] as! String)
                    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(point.x), CLLocationDegrees(point.y))
                    let title = attraction["name"] as! String
                    let typeRawValue = Int((attraction["type"] as! String))!
                    let type = HumanAnnotationType(rawValue: typeRawValue)!
                    let subtitle = attraction["subtitle"] as! String
                    let annotation = HumanAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate, title: title, subtitle: subtitle, type: type)
                    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the plist:
[image]
If you need further code to understand what's going on please don't hesitate to ask and thank you for anyone's help in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary`? Use Swift dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy I did consider it and as you know it asks for the types that will go into the dictionary to be declared but when I tried string types or even any types, it gave me further errors.

Comment: Are you sure that the root object of the plist is a dictionary? You're using an  array enumerator.

Comment: @vadian yes I should have added a screenshot of the plist for more information.  Attaching one now and the root is an Array.  Your insight did help though.

Comment: Just remembered @rmaddy that the NSDictionary is being used because this was initially written the former days of Swift and now I'm converting the code for it to build at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, your last comment means you have successfully converted your code, but seeing your image of the plist, your code can be re-written like this:

```
    if
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GeorgiaHumanAnnotations", ofType: "plist"),
        let dictArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) as? [[String: Any]]
    {
        for attraction in dictArray {
            let point = CGPointFromString(attraction["location"] as! String)
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(point.x), CLLocationDegrees(point.y))
            let title = attraction["name"] as! String
            let typeRawValue = Int((attraction["type"] as! String))!
            let type = HumanAnnotationType(rawValue: typeRawValue)!
            let subtitle = attraction["subtitle"] as! String
            let annotation = HumanAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate, title: title, subtitle: subtitle, type: type)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
```